# how to map the string using python 

Tags: python, string

this is my code :

```
a= ''' ddwqqf{x}'''
def b():
    ...

c=b(a,{'x':'!!!!!'})
print c
```

i want to get `ddwqqf!!!!!` ,

so how to create the `b`  function ,

thanks

**updated:**

but how to do this thing :

```
a= ''' ddwqqf{x},{'a':'aaaa'}'''

c = a.format(x="!!!!!")

d= open('a.txt','a')
d.write(c)
```

it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 8, in <module>
    c = a.format(x="!!!!!")
KeyError: "'a'"
```

**updated2:**

this is the string:

```
'''
{
    'skill': {x_1},
    'power': {x_2},
    'magic': {x_3},
    'level': {x_4},
    'weapon': {
        0 : {
            'item': {
                'weight': 40,
                'target': 1,
                'defence': 100,
                'name': u'\uff75\uff70\uff78\uff7f\uff70\uff84',
                'attack': 100,
                'type': 1
            },
        },
        1 : {
            'item': {
                'weight': 40,
                'target': 1,
                'defence': 100,
                'name': u'\uff75\uff70\uff78\uff7f\uff70\uff84',
                'attack': 100,
                'type': 1
            },
        },
        2 : {
            'item': {
                'weight': 40,
                'target': 1,
                'defence': 100,
                'name': u'\uff75\uff70\uff78\uff7f\uff70\uff84',
                'attack': 100,
                'type': 1
            },
        }
       ......
    }
}
'''
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your second example is very confusing.

Comment: i want to map  many different  Variable  into a dict , and  create many dict like this  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
def b(a, d):
    return a.format(**d)
```

This works in Python 2.6 or above.  Of course you would not need to define a function for this:

```
a = " ddwqqf{x}"
c = a.format(x="!!!!!")
```

will be enough.

**Edit** regarding your update:

```
a = " ddwqqf{x},{{'a':'aaaa'}}"
```

to avoid substitutions for the second pair of braces.

**Another Edit**: I don't really know where your string comes from and what's the context of all this.  One solution might be

```
import re
d = {"x_1": "1", "x_2": "2", "x_3": "3", "x_4": "4"}
re.sub(r"\{([a-z_0-9]+)\}", lambda m: d[m.group(1)], s)
```

where `s` is your string.

Comment: did you have other way to do this , because the string is very big , if i change {} to {{}}  , that is a hard work to me . look the updated2 .